# C++ pushing vector <myNewType*>

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, push

I am trying to push data to my vector, but I'm met with an error:

> expression must have class type

This is my code:

```
float calcX(float u, float v) 
{
    return (((-90.0*pow(u, 5) + 225.0*pow(u, 4) - 270.0*pow(u, 3) + 180.0*pow(u, 2) - 45.0*u)*cos(pi*v)));
}

float calcY(float u, float v) 
{
    return (160.0*pow(u, 4) - 320.0*pow(u, 3) + 160.0*pow(u, 2) - 5.0f);
}

float calcZ(float u, float v) 
{
    return (((-90.0*pow(u, 5) + 225.0*pow(u, 4) - 270.0*pow(u, 3) + 180.0*pow(u, 2) - 45.0*u)*sin(pi*v)));
}

typedef float point3[3];
std::vector <point3*> createEggBuffor(int n=20) 
{   
    std::vector <point3*> egg;

    for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < n; v++) {
            egg[u][v][0].push_back(calcX(static_cast<float>(u) / (n - 1), static_cast<float>(v) / (n - 1)));
            egg[u][v][1].push_back(calcY(static_cast<float>(u) / (n - 1), static_cast<float>(v) / (n - 1)));
            egg[u][v][2].push_back(calcZ(static_cast<float>(u) / (n - 1), static_cast<float>(v) / (n - 1)));            
        }
    }       
    return egg;
}
```

What this error means?

Comment: what is calcX/Y/Z? what line does the error say it occurs?

Comment: You can't call `.push_back()` on a `float`.

Comment: Why are you using what appears to be a vector of pointers into C-style arrays, rather than just a vector of vectors?

Comment: do you have more of the code that I can see, and the line in which your compiler states the errors occur?

Comment: I've added more of my code - definition of calcX, calcY and calcZ functions. This error appears on three lines, where I am pushing  data to my vector.

Answer (score 1):

`egg[u]` is a `point3*`. `egg[u][v]` is a `point3` (which is an array of 3 floats). So `egg[u][v][N]` is a `float`. `float` is a built-in type, and does not have a member function named `push_back`, or any members at all. The error is telling you that, since it is not a class type, you can't use the dot operator to access members of it (since it doesn't have any).

If you're trying to push back elements onto your `egg` vector, it would look like this:

```
egg.push_back(something);
```

Where `something` is an expression of type `point3*`.

Comment: Ok, I used an assignment operator instead of push_back, but there is still a problem. My code compiles without errors, but then it's crashing. I have this communication: "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is avalable."

Comment: @Antipoison: You mean you're doing `egg[u][v][0] = some_float_value;`? Yes, that will probably crash if your vector doesn't have any elements in it, which it doesn't in the code you've presented.

Comment: Ok, I'm so much begginer that I don't exactly understand how I should push data returned by calc functions to this vector.

Comment: @Antipoison: It's hard for me to answer that, because you are using such an odd data structure. I don't know why you are using a vector of pointers to arrays, but I can't imagine many situations where such a thing is useful. I would suggest changing it. But before suggesting exactly what you should change it to, I would need to know what problem you are trying to solve. I would suggest opening a new question, describing the problem you are trying to solve, and asking for what data structure you should use to store it.

Comment: @Antipoison: To elaborate on why I don't think you are using the correct data structure. In order to store items in the vector you've created, first you would need to declare an array separate from your vector, like this: `float arr[3];`. Then you could push back a pointer to that array like this: `egg.push_back(&arr);`. That's not really what you want to do, is it? If you really wanted pointers to arrays, I would assume you would have already declared some arrays that you want pointers to.

Comment: What I am trying to do is generating a 3d model of egg in opengl, built with points or lines. My object (egg) is described by parametric equation (calc functions). What data structure you suggest?

Comment: @Antipoison: Try creating a struct like `struct point3 { float x, y, z; };`, then store those by value, not pointer. `std::vector<point3>`. If you need your points to have an array like interface, then you can use `std::array<float, 3>` instead, but again, store them by value, not pointer.

Comment: Ok, I followed your advice and created vector: `std::vector <std::array <float, 3>> egg(n);`, but when I am trying push data into it, this way: `egg[u][v][0] = calcX(static_cast<float>(u) / (n - 1), static_cast<float>(v) / (n - 1));`, there is still error `expression must have pointer-to-object type`. How I should do it?